# Voicexml how to store input into a global variable

Tags: global-variables, vxml, voicexml

I'm creating a voicexml appliacation.

I want to store an user input into a global variable.

I wondered, the input should be stored in the fieldvar. shouldn't it? After I tried it with this, i tried to store it in an global variable:

```
<assign name="myvar" expr="'myinput'"/>
```

but somehow it didn't work. I used  value `expr="var"` as expr.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<vxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml 
   http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/vxml.xsd"
   version="2.0">


<var name="myProdukt" />


<form id="test">

<field name="var">
<prompt bargein="true" bargeintype="hotword" >Sagen Sie ein Produkt</prompt>

<grammar root="main" version="1.0" xml:lang="de-DE">

  <rule id="main" scope="public">
    <one-of>
      <item> p1 </item>
      <item> p2 </item>
      <item> p3 </item>
      <item> p4   </item>
    </one-of>
  </rule>

</grammar>



<filled>
<assign name="myProdukt" expr="<value expr="var"/>"/>
</filled>

</field>


</form>

<<!--[...] Here i want to use the input.-->

</vxml>
```

thanks in advance

---------------EDIT:

now i used this:

```
<filled>
test
<assign name="myProdukt" expr="var" />
</filled>
```

I only changed that. The Applications says "test" but then there is an error.

---

It isn'T allowed to use "var" instead I used an other name :-)

Comment: Well it seems to be more or less the same. the application says "test" in the filled tags, but then it says that an error occurred and the the application stops.

Comment: seems to be <assign name="myProdukt" expr="var" />, but the is correct I think

Comment: @Tyzak.  I agree that the answer below is correct.  Once the assign has completed, the call will transition to the next unfilled field or the next form.  If it reaches the end of the document, most platforms will just hang up.

Comment: Got it! it isn't allowed to declare  a variabkle with VAR

Comment: @Tyzak Oh yes!  I forgot about that constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try a simple assignment of field `var` to the variable `myProdukt` like so ?

```
<filled>
    <assign name="myProdukt" expr="var"/>
</filled>
```

Which would be fine except that according to [`Section 5.1, Variables and Expressions`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-voicexml20-20040316/#dml5.1) of the Voice XML specification:

> VoiceXML variables, including form
>   item variables, must not contain
>   ECMAScript reserved words.

So, you'll need to rename the field `var` to something that is not a reserved word in *ECMAscript*, say `productSelection`:

```
<field name="productSelection"> 
    <!-- .. prompt, grammar as before .. -->
    <filled>
        <assign name="myProdukt" expr="productSelection"/>
    </filled>
</field>
```

Comment: that should work, (https://studio.tellme.com/vxml2/ovw/variables.html says so too) but it doesn't ?! I'm very confused :>